# Erro ao compilar um programa modularizado em c

Tags: c, array, arquivo-header

Fiz um programa em que lê strings de um arquivo separadas por `-` (hífen) e salva cada string em uma posição de um vetor de struct.

Ao compilar, gera a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> array type has incomplete element type

Pesquisei na net e vi que uma solução seria escrever a implementação da struct dentro do arquivo *estruturas.h*, porém, eu gostaria de deixar a implementação oculta, deixando apenas os protótipos no .h

Seria possível?

Segue o código:

#### main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "estruturas.h"

int main()
{
    String vetor_de_string[MAX];
    leArquivo(vetor_de_string);

    return 0;
}
```

#### estruturas.h

```
#ifndef ESTRUTURAS_H_
#define ESTRUTURAS_H_
#define MAX 50

typedef struct string String;

void leArquivo(String *s);

#endif
```

#### estruturas.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "estruturas.h"

struct string
{
    char nome[20];
};

void leArquivo(struct string *s)
{
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    if(!f)
    {
        printf("*** Erro: Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo! ***\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int l = 0, i = 0;
    char aux, a[20], b[20], c[20];

    while((aux = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
    {
        if(aux == '\n')
            l++;
        if(l > 0)
        {
            fscanf(f, "%19[^-]s", a);   
            aux = fgetc(f); 
            fscanf(f, "%19[^-]s", b);
            aux = fgetc(f);
            fscanf(f, "%19[^\n]s", c);

            strcpy(s[i].nome, a);
            strcpy(s[++i].nome, b);
            strcpy(s[++i].nome, c);
            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: O que você chama de ocultar a implementação? Implementação de que?

Comment: Eu me referi a implementação da struct string. Não quero implementar (definir) ela no arquivo cabeçalho (header) chamado: estruturas.h Mas o Dan Getz resolveu meu problema. No mais, obrigado pelo interesse. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É impossível construir um vetor dum tipo sem saber o tamanho do tipo, porque o tamanho do vetor é o tamanho de cada elemento multiplicado pelo número de elementos. Em *estruturas.c* é sabido que cada `String` tem um tamanho de 20, mas em *main.c* não, então é impossível saber qual é o tamanho de `vetor_de_string`. Então ou tem que por a definição de `struct string` no header, ou tem que usar somente ponteiros ao tipo. (É sabido o tamanho dum ponteiro a um tipo, sem precisar saber o tamanho do tipo.) Por exemplo, pode modificar o tipo do argumento da `leArquivo()` de `String*` para `String**` e adicionar o seguinte:

### estructuras.h

```
String *novaString();
```

### estructuras.c

```
String *novaString() {
    return malloc(sizeof(struct string));
}
```

e usa `novaString()` em `main()` para alocar o vetor:

```
int i;
String *vetor_de_string[MAX];
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    vetor_de_string[i] = novaString();
}
```

Depois, se não está a terminar o programa logo, é preciso desalocar os elementos de `vetor_de_string`:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    free(vetor_de_string[i]);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Dan Getz. Já tinha um tempo que estava quebrando cabeça com isso. rsrs Valeu!!